# Raspberry 4 not booting - green and red light not blinking - sd card problem?

Tags: raspbian, boot, sd-card, pi-4

My raspberry 4 bought on amazon doesn't want to boot, both red and green light are on but none of them are blinking even when plug / unplug the sd card, no reaction from the raspberry, my screen obviously receive no signal and both my mouse and keyboard are not emitting any light.

Here is what I tried :

- tried another sd card I took from one of the working raspberry I found at my school -> it worked and I was able to use my raspberry with the graphical interface working.
- formatted my raspberry pi using Gparted in fat32, downloaded noob from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/ and tried to install it -> didn't work.
- formatted my sd card using "sd card formatter" on windows, then installed the raspian iso image on my sd card using BalenaEtcher.
- tried to recover the BOOT EEPROM to the factory default settings by using Raspberry Pi Imager as recommended on the "STICKY : Is your raspberry pi not booting" https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=437084

At this point I think the problem come from my sd card but is there a way to repair it before buying another one ? or can the problem still come from the installation ?

Thanks you in advance for helping me !

Comment: why did you recover the BOOT EEPROM when clearly you pi booted with a working sd card? what is the make/model of the sd card that doesn't work (or is it some generic thing bundled with the amazon purchase?)

Comment: oh, and if you boot the pi with no sd card in it, what happens?

Comment: "none of them are blinking even when plug / unplug the sd card" I don't think this is a good idea.